# API request to custom port on subdomain not working

Tags: apache, next.js, laravel-8, cloudflare, ubuntu-20.04

I have deployed Laravel-Next.js app on `Ubuntu 20.04 Apache server` using `Digital Ocean`. I am serving the Next.js app on `port 3000` and Laravel API on `port 2083`.

So I have created two virtual hosts, one virtual host is listening to `port 80` and proxy the request to `port 3000` so that Next.js can handle the request. Another virtual host is configured to accept the request at `port 2083` which points to laravel public folder so that APIs can be served.

Now when I load website with IP address, the page loads correctly and Laravel API is served without any error but when I reqeust the same website using a subdomain configured through `Cloudflare`, the Next.js page loads but all API calls are failed with status code 525 and no message.

In the same way if I request Laravel web route using `IP_ADDRESS:2083` (in browser) then I get the response but when I request the page using `example.domain.com:2083` then I get following error

```
Error 525
SSL handshake failed
```

I have switched my SSL/TLS encryption mode to Flexible and switched On "Always Use HTTPS" under "Edge Certificate" tab as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627705/4494813) but that didn't help.

**virtual host for handing port 80**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

**virtual host for handing port 2083**

```
<VirtualHost *:2083>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel-project/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/laravel-project/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
Listen 2083

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**firewall allowed ports**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                                   
2083                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                              
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)                          
2083 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Quoting https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/ `Cloudflare Access does not support port numbers in URLs. Port numbers are stripped from requests for URLs protected through Cloudflare Access.` Does that help?

Comment: @barrycarter then what could be the solution?

Comment: You might need to upgrade your Cloudflare subscription or find a solution that doesn't use a port number

Answer (score 0):

Barrycarter's comment leads me to google in right direction that leads me to come across portzilla. Below I have described the important steps to work with it

**Step 1: Install Portzilla on Cloudflare**

On your Cloudflare dashboard, click on your domain then click on Apps from sidebar and search for portzilla.

**Step 2: Configure the path for custom port**

[image]

In `Route Name` field, input anything.

In `Route URL` field, enter your `domain_name` + `/path_name` that will be replaced by `:port` in url.

In `Route Target` field, select first option that is `Proxies to a port on my domain`

In `Target Port` field, enter the port number number that should be targeted for given `Route URL`. In my case target port would be `2083`.

So for example if my `Route URL` is `example.domain.com/xyz` and `Route target` is `2083` then portzilla will convert this url to `example.domain.com:2083`.

You can enable use `HTTP option` if you still get Cloudflare 525 error.

At last click on `Save changes and install on all pages`.

For video tutorial and documentation, [refer this link](https://networkchimp.fun/tutorials/portzilla-api.html?ref=install).